# Sign Up / Login with just OTP

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-4.x

I had a request to build a website for a targeted market that is allow its user to signup using their phone number only without entering email address just like mobile apps nowadays. I know this can be done with php framework such laravel + Firebase, but I'm just wondering, is this possible to be done with joomla 3.x or joomla 4.x maybe?

Comment: Are you planning to still have a user name and password? Do you intend to replace the notification aspects of not having an email address with the phone number?

Answer (score 1):

In the Joomla Extension Directory there is a free OTP plugin for Joomla available that uses an external commercial SMS (Text message) provider:

**OTP Verification For Joomla**
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/otp-verification-for-joomla/

Maybe you can use the plugin + its SMS provider as solution, or use the code to develop your own Firebase OTP plugin?

Comment: I'm aware of this extension but what I'm looking is, to signup without an email address. Is it something technically possible with joomla?

Comment: The plugin mentioned allows registration without an email address.